# Collision failing while moving left in libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using gird based collision detection in my game and everything is working except one thing, when the player is on a tile and moves left he falls through the tile. This is happening because the grid spot updates way faster when moving left then right because the players grid position shifts based on coordinates. For example: if the player is at 100, he won't update until he reaches 150, the cell range is 100 - 150(Cell size is 50) but if you move left you will be at 99 which is included in the 50 - 100 cell area. Here is an image to really help better explaining

Note: The red represents the players grid position and the pink rectangle is where the players animation will be played, so the pink shouldn't be able to go through tiles.

[image: Example]

Here is my players update for the falling

```
    public void checkFall(Vector3 positionToCheck) {
    if (positionToCheck != null) {

        if (this.position.y <= positionToCheck.y + MapGrid.CELL_SIZE && positionToCheck.z == -1)
            canFall = false;


    }else
            canFall = true;
}
```

Here is the collision detection for falling

```
    public Vector3 updateFall() {

    /* ================================== */
    /* ====*Exclusively for falling*===== */
    /* ================================== */
    if (mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) entity.getGridPosition().x][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y] &&
            (mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) entity.getGridPosition().x][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y] &&
                    entity.getPosition().x + 1 >= entity.getGridPosition().x)) {
        p.x = (int) ((entity.getGridPosition().x) * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE);
        p.y = (int) ((entity.getGridPosition().y) * MapGrid.CELL_SIZE);
        p.z = -1;
        return p;
    }



    return null;

}
```

and here is how it checks in case you are curious

```
    player.checkFall(collisionHandler.updateFall());
```

The z aspect of the vector3 is so that when it returns p, it doesn't get the information of lets say "updateMoveRight"

I have tried checking for the right side being true while the actual position is false but then you can not fall unless you have dug 2 spots, which is not what I want. I want the player to be able to be in a tight fit (1 tile wide) everything in the game is 1 tile wide.

Any help is incredibly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed your conditional with the magnitude distance you should be able to check either left or right so:

instead of:

```
if (mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) entity.getGridPosition().x][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y] &&
        (mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) entity.getGridPosition().x][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y] &&
                entity.getPosition().x + 1 >= entity.getGridPosition().x)) {
```

change to:

```
if (mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) entity.getGridPosition().x][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y] &&
        (mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) entity.getGridPosition().x][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y] &&
                Math.abs(entity.getGridPosition().x - entity.getPosition().x) < 1 ) {
```

you can change the number 1 to be larger if your object moves more than 2 pixels per frame.

If you put a large value in you can always move the entity to the correct position once it is detected so it wont fall offset by a few pixels by making a setter for Position like so:

```
    if (mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) entity.getGridPosition().x][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y] &&
        (mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) entity.getGridPosition().x][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y] &&
                Math.abs(entity.getGridPosition().x - entity.getPosition().x) < 10 ) {
        entity.setPositionX(entity.getGridPosition().x);
```

also why is :

```
(mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) entity.getGridPosition().x][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y]
```

in there twice?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing logically is that you can only fall if both sides of the pink rectangle are over grid positions that are holes. So you will have to check two separate grid positions in your `updateFall()` method, not just one.

Comment: But the red square itself is a grid position, it doesn't get smaller then the size of those rectangles

Comment: Don't understand what you're saying--ignore the red rectangle. Just check if the left and right of the pink rectangle are over empty space.

Comment: That is violating the grid collision system, the player himself is only one tile, there is no right side of him. If he was two tiles this problem would have been fixed already.

Comment: Your desired logic is impossible to implement if you don't check two different grid locations. If the user visually sees the pink rectangle, that's what you need to determine whether the second grid position to check should be on the left or right.

Comment: It shouldn't be impossible, if the grid position is to the left and the right has something there dont allow fall

Comment: "The right has something" == have to check second grid position.

Comment: No if you move left, the grid position goes left, so if you move left and there is something to the right of your grid position

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I wrote, because you keep agreeing with what I said. You're saying if the player's grid position is over a hole, you still don't want them to fall if the grid position to the right is solid. So check the player's grid position and the position to the right. That's two grid positions. In some cases, you would want to check the grid position to the left instead. I assume this depends if the pink rectangle is more to the left relative to grid position than to the right.

Comment: I want to accomlish this with my player only having one grid position, it is for a project

Comment: Ah, OK. Whenever someone asks a question on here that seems to have nonsensical restrictions, it turns out to be homework. :)  This is tough to answer because I don't know what all your requirements are. It could be done in an absurdly inefficient way that might work with your requirements: Every grid position also contains information about whether there is a wall on the left and whether there is a wall on the right. And somewhere you store the player's last grid position and use that to decide if the current grid position keeps in mind whether it is solid to either the left or right.

Comment: That's not perfect if the player has mid-air control like Mario. Mario could be traveling right as he falls onto the left edge of a platform, so the above algorithm would check the wrong side of the grid position. I suppose it comes down to how you are selecting the player's grid position. Is the pink position updated first and rounded off to a red position, or is the pink position merely an offset from the red position.

Comment: The pink isnt updated, the red is updated and the pink is only allowed to move if the red says it is okay. The pinks grid position is in red

Comment: But surely you store the pink's position from the last frame? Are you sure you understand your requirements correctly, that you are not allowed to read any data from more than one grid position in any frame? If that's the case, how could you possibly check if you can walk left or right either?

Comment: because u can check the left when ur not there, if gridPosition.x - 1

Comment: That's what I've been suggesting the whole time. Do the same thing to see if you can fall.

Comment: I did to no result check the end of the question, i check right because when u move left u r in the right position and checking left would check the one two to the left when u move left just a little

Comment: Let me chime in here, and see if I have the problem well defined in my head.  You need to able to check just one grid position, for homework purposes, to see if you can fall or not, right?  And did you try checking gridPosition.x + 1 as well?  Because it seems like you're saying the red square is updated based on which direction you're going, right?  So if you go right, then you have to check gridPosition.x and gridPosition.x + 1, whereas if you go left you need to check gridPosition.x and gridPosition.x - 1.